# How fabric work with 'sudo su user'

Tags: python, sudo, fabric

My request is simple:

1. ssh to a remote server with user0
2. switch user to user1 using: 'sudo su user1'
3. list all items in current folder

My expected code:

```
def startRedis():
    run('sudo su - user1')
    print(run('ls'))
```

However, it ends with out: `user1@server:~$`
And waiting for my interactive command forever, never executing the second line. It seems `sudo su` opened a new shell.

Can anyone help solving this simple task?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `sudo_user` property in env. this way fabric will switch user to the desired user.

Official doc: [http://docs.fabfile.org/](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/env.html#sudo-user)

Password for switching user can be specified in the env. itself to avoid getting a prompt when the method is invoked.

`fabfile.py`

```py
from fabric.api import env, sudo

env.sudo_user='user1'
env.password = '***'

def list_items():
    sudo('ls')
```

Run below command & specify the hosts after `-H`

```
fab -H host1 list_items
```

Comment: it would work also using `env.user` if the key is authorized for any user *in* sudoers, and it would fail, even if `env.sudo_user` is set, if the ssh key is for a user *not in* sudoers group. So the answer could work but is not 100% correct.

Comment: Yes, the sudoers group will be looked up for checking if the user is having required privileges. In that case, the program won't keep waiting, rather it will exit with the respective error message.